# Any 'non-destructive' alternative to knife project?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I would like to cut a shape out of a mesh, but in an non-destructive way.
Like the knife project, but then, as a modifier. Or as the boolean modifier, but then without the geometry of the operand.

Comment: could you please explain more in detail why you want that, show some screenshots? Maybe there's an alternative to Knife Project and Boolean for your project...

Comment: But "without the geometry of the operand" implies like in Knife Project, that this geometry is in some way applied on the object. If you remove geometry which is needed for a non-destructive approach, how should the modifier know which geometry should be used?

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thanks for taking the time and trying to anwser my question. What I want, basically, is to cut a hole in the mesh the way knife project does, but in a non destructive way, as a modifier, so that I can still tweak both the base shape and the operand shape. I have a mesh with a subdivision modifier applied to it. A boolean modifier (applied as 'difference') after the subdivision modifier keeps the mesh closed (usinng part of the operand geometry), but I want to cut a hole in it.

Comment: Use booltool addon, which does some automatic operations to hide the cutter object from viewport and render but lets you edit the wire frame.

Comment: Josh Gambrell on YouTube has many videos on boolean workflow

Comment: Hi @GordonBrinkmann, thanks for taking the time and trying to anwser my question. Well off course I wouldn't remove the operand geometry. I'm just looking for a boolean-like 'difference' modifier, which cuts a part out of the mesh at the intersection between the two operands (resulting in an open mesh - with a hole in it). But since knife project is a destructive operation, I'd rather not use is because I would like to still be able to tweak both the base mesh (with subdivision modifier) and the operand mesh.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're looking for:

[image]

Another way of putting this is, you want to boolean, but then you want to discard any geometry that doesn't lie on the surface of your pre-boolean mesh.  Putting things that way makes it more clear that yes, this is possible.

One possibility is using Geometry Nodes.  In 3.0, we could do this:

[image]

To put words to this, we are booleaning, then we are testing for proximity against the faces of our original geometry, then discarding any vertices for which the distance to our original geometry is greater than some fudge factor to take care of imprecisions (0.001 in this case, mostly just to demonstrate it; it can be smaller.)

If you would rather not use geometry nodes, the same operations can be achieved by testing against a (probably linked, parented) duplicate.  Boolean, vertex weight edit to add all verts to a proximity groups, vertex weight proximity from duplicate, followed by a mask.